# Pass post details to new page (Firebase in Flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter

**Multi level Flutter Page**

I need to add the functionality of pressing a post card and it loading a more detailed page with that posts information. So far I have developed the listview displaying the post cards and have wrapped them with an InkWell that pushes to the detailed page.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Friends')),
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('posts')
                .where('uid', isEqualTo: widget.uid)
                .get(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
              return ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: (snapshot.data! as dynamic).docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    DocumentSnapshot snap =
                        (snapshot.data! as dynamic).docs[index];

                    return Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                            borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            InkWell(
                              child: Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                width: 140,
                                height: 140,
                                child: ClipRRect(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                    child: Container(
                                      
                                        child: Material(
                                          child: Ink.image(
                                            
                                              image:
                                                  NetworkImage(snap['postUrl']),
                                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                              child: InkWell(
                                                onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                                                  context,
                                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                                      builder: (context,) =>
                                                          DetailedPage(uid: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)),
                                                ),
                                              )),
                                        ))),
                              ),
                            ),
```